# Simple functions convergence under different topologies

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, simple-functions

In Serge Lang's *Real and Functional Analysis*, first part of Lemma 3.1 (p.129) states

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence of step mappings. Then there exists a subsequence which converges pointwise almost everywhere.

Here "step mappings" by Lang is the same as "simple functions" in other texts, and every such function $f_n: X\to E$ is from a measure space to a general Banach space. Also, what he means by a "Cauchy sequence" is in terms of the $L^1$-norm. That is, for every $\epsilon>0$, ther exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\int_X |f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$ whenever $m,n>N$.

> **Question:** Is there an example of such a sequence of simple functions $\{f_n\}$ that is Cauchy under the $L^1$-norm but does *not* converge pointwise outside of a measure-zero set? Or, can we push the lemma further to conclude the sequence itself must converge pointwise almost everywhere, not just a subsequence?

Comment: No you cannot push the lemma further. Take a sliding function, i.e on the interval $[0,1]$, start with a constant $1$-function. Then the indicator of the firdt half, then the second half. Then the 3 indicators of the thirds, and so on. The areas decrease to $0$, but you converge nowhere.